# Batch file nested for loop throws "| was unexpected at this time"

Tags: batch-file

I am attempting to store the return of a `dir` command into a variable. So far all I've found requires a `for /f` loop. This call is made from within another `for /f` loop and I am having issues with it. Here are snippets for the relevant parts of the code:

```
set "list=list.txt"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%D in (%list%) do (
     set "path_to=%%D"
     ...
     ...
     ...
     for /f "delims=" %%Z in ('dir /b "%path_to%\..\..\.." | find /c /v ""') do (echo %%Z)
)
```

I am using `%path_to%` instead of `!path_to!` because the variable is outside of this second for loop.

Comment: `...because the variable is outside of this second for loop` - it is still within the outer `for` loop (where it was defined) and therefore must be delay-expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape pipe with carret `^|` if pipe is used in subject of FOR loop. Pipe is a special character in batch files.